# FullCalendar JSON not populating calendar

Tags: arrays, json, fullcalendar

I think I am missing something.  I have set up Full Calendar, and have the default version working, but now am adding my own JSON, and it is not.

Code in the calendar page is

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
        },
        defaultDate: '2017-09-12',
        editable: true,
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: {
            url: 'php/get-events.php',
            error: function() {
                $('#script-warning').show();
            }
        },
        loading: function(bool) {
            $('#loading').toggle(bool);
        }
    });

});
```

I am learning how to encode JSON as I go along, and I found a tutorial online that gave me some code that seems to work. I have amended the original code in get-events.php to read like this (snippet with DB details taken out)...

```
// Require our Event class and datetime utilities
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/utils.php';

// Short-circuit if the client did not give us a date range.
if (!isset($_GET['start']) || !isset($_GET['end'])) {
    die("Please provide a date range.");
}

// Parse the start/end parameters.
// These are assumed to be ISO8601 strings with no time nor timezone, like "2013-12-29".
// Since no timezone will be present, they will parsed as UTC.
$range_start = parseDateTime($_GET['start']);
$range_end = parseDateTime($_GET['end']);

// Parse the timezone parameter if it is present.
$timezone = null;
if (isset($_GET['timezone'])) {
    $timezone = new DateTimeZone($_GET['timezone']);
}

class Emp {
    public $id = "";
    public $title  = "";
    public $start = "";
    public $url = "";
}

while(!$JAN->atEnd()) {              
    e = new Emp();
    $e->id = $JAN->getColumnVal("ID");
    $e->title  = $JAN->getColumnVal("TITLE");
    $e->start = $JAN->getColumnVal("DATE")."T".$JAN->getColumnVal("TIME");
    $e->url = "meeting_info.php?ID=".$JAN->getColumnVal("ID");
    echo json_encode($e);  
    $JAN->moveNext();
 }
 $JAN->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record

// Read and parse our events JSON file into an array of event data arrays.
$json = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../json/events.json');
$input_arrays = json_decode($json, true);

// Accumulate an output array of event data arrays.
$output_arrays = array();
foreach ($input_arrays as $array) {

// Convert the input array into a useful Event object
$event = new Event($array, $timezone);

// If the event is in-bounds, add it to the output
if ($event->isWithinDayRange($range_start, $range_end)) {
    $output_arrays[] = $event->toArray();
}
}

// Send JSON to the client.
echo json_encode($output_arrays);
```

When I run the `get-events.php` page on it's own I get what I am assuming to be a correctly encoded JSON returned, one example in the array is ...

```
{"id":20,"title":"Executive Committee Meeting","start":"2017-05-01T00:00:00","url":"meeting_info.php?ID=20"}
```

Can anybody tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: You need to run json_encode() on a complete array of PHP objects, not on each one individually. In your loop, add each Emp to an array, and then encode the array, when the loop ends. If you look in your browser's network tab at the result of your ajax request, I think you'll likely see a string of individual objects, but not wrapped in array (square) brackets, and not separated by commas, meaning the JSON is invalid. There's also a good chance there's an error message in the console too about the invalid data format

Comment: @ADyson add it as an answer! :-)

Comment: @Don'tPanic good point, I should really, I'm 99% sure that's the answer. Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `json_encode()` on a complete array of PHP objects, not on each one individually. In your loop, add each Emp to an array, and then encode the array, when the loop ends.

If you look in your browser's network tab at the result of your ajax request, I think you're very likely to see a string of individual objects, but not wrapped in array (square) brackets, and not separated by commas, meaning the JSON is invalid. There's also a good chance there's an error message in your browser's console about the invalid data format. It's best to check this rather than assuming your JSON is correct. There are also online JSON validator tools you can paste it into, to validate the JSON in isolation.

Something like this should work better:

```
$events = array();

while(!$JAN->atEnd()) {              
    e = new Emp();
    $e->id = $JAN->getColumnVal("ID");
    $e->title  = $JAN->getColumnVal("TITLE");
    $e->start = $JAN->getColumnVal("DATE")."T".$JAN->getColumnVal("TIME");
    $e->url = "meeting_info.php?ID=".$JAN->getColumnVal("ID");
    $events[] = $e; //add event to the array
    $JAN->moveNext();
 }

 echo json_encode($events); //encode the whole array as a coherent piece of JSON

//P.S. no need to run moveFirst really, since the request is going to end, and discard the resultset anyhow. Depending on your data access technique, you possibly need to close the recordset though, to avoid locking etc.
```

What you need your code to generate (and what fullCalendar is expecting), is a JSON array - here's a simple example containing 2 elements (representing events):

```
[
  { "id":20, "title":"Executive Committee Meeting", "start":"2017-05-01T00:00:00", "url":"meeting_info.php?ID=20" },
  { "id":21, "title":"Another Boring Committee Meeting", "start":"2017-05-02T00:00:00", "url":"meeting_info.php?ID=21" }
]
```

The example code I've given above should generate an array which is in the same format as this JSON sample.

Comment: I followed your code (thank you so much!), and placed it in a separate php file, and it delivers a perfect JSON array, thank you!  I am still confused as to how to integrate this new JSON array into the get-events.php file that Full Calendar calls upon.  The get-events.php file seems to decode the JSON details from a static file.  How can I integrate this?  I am so confused!

Comment: I'm also confused then. What you showed me above you said was a sample from get-events.php. All I've done above is take a small sample from your get-events.php code and change it slightly. So you just need to replace the relevant bit of your existing code in that file, with my version. I don't know what you mean about "decoding from a static file" - the wording of your question clearly says you've taken out the database code, so presumably you're fetching your events from a database. Where does a static file come into it?

Comment: P.S. The JSON I gave above is just an example of the desired output which hopefully will be generated by the updated version of the PHP code, it's not something you need to add into your application. It's an example of what you should be able to see in your browser's developer tools when examining the response from the ajax request to get-events.php

Comment: I am so sorry for confusing you, I really appreciate your help in this. I meant to put the entire file on the question, but didn't. There are pieces of code in the get-events.php file I didn;t include, and one part links to a static .json file, which is confusing the heck out of me.  Should I edit the original question to add that code in there, or is there another way I can show you it?

Comment: You can edit the original question, yes, if you think it's relevant. What does that JSON file contain? More events? Are they intended to be merged with the stuff coming from the database?

Comment: the json file contains a json arry like { "title": "All Day Event", "start": "2017-09-01"  }, I'll add the code in the original question right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155501/discussion-between-bill-teale-and-adyson).